# PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is fired after some beans are initialized

Tags: java, spring

I have a custom PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configured in XML.
Then I have a custom XML bean definition

```
<bean id="propertySourceProducer" class="PropertySourcesProducer" />

<bean id="someProperties" class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="propertySources">
          <bean factory-bean="propertySourceProducer" factory-method="createPropertySources" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="someBean" class="package.SomeBean">
    <property name="someProp" value="${placeholder.val}" />
</bean>
```

The problem is that the someBean.someProp is set to `${placeholder.val}`

I've run the debugger patiently and it seems that the someBean is constructed before the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is constructed. Then it visits BeanDefinitions and finds correct value for `${placeholder.val}`. But it's too late.

What is interesting it works fine in integration test context (slightly different configuration).

I've tried setting `depends-on="someProperties"` in `someBean` definition with no success.

Comment: What are differences between this config and your integration tests config?

Comment: This config file remains as is in integration tests. The second xml file contains just datasource and tx manager configuration which is different for tests.So I replace second file for tests.

Comment: This is strange as property placeholder configurer is a bean definition post porcessor and should be instantiated and then process definitions for regular beans, replace the placeholders and only then normal beans should be instantiated. Is your somebean regular bean and not some kind of bean definition post processor?

Comment: Yes. It is a regular bean.
I'm starting to suspect that PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer uses propertySourceProducer which then depends on DataSource for producing custom DB-backed PropertySource.
Do you think this may lead Spring to decision for instatntinating it later?

Comment: Looks like the cause since it is the only difference between regular and test context.

Comment: Since you are reading configuration from DB when context is being initialized, you might want to consider whether to read your beans property value just in time instead (maybe with a cache), so when you change your DB you dont have to restart your whole application for changes to take effect.

Comment: We had such approach. But I wanted to use property placeholders for built-in spring beans as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug/feature in Spring.
I've tried another approach, with loading DB into `java.util.Properties` and passing to `<context:property-placeholder>`. The same result.

The problem seems to be different.

My bean `someBean` is a simple, plain bean. However it is a dependency to `FactoryBean` (not visible in the config).

```
<bean id="otherBean" class="this.is.implementation.of.FactoryBean">
   <property name="dependency" ref="someBean" />
</bean>
```

Even if `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` is a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` and should be instatninated first, Spring creates `someBean` first. I guess that this is because it's needed for `FactoryBean`.

However `FactoryBean` itself is created later. So the order of instantination is

- dataSource
- someBean (missing properties)
- propertySourceProducer, PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
- FactoryBean and all other beans

This is ridiculous and works fine when `someBean` is not a dependency of `FactoryBean`.

I don't understand why it happens in `WebApplicationContext` and works fine in integration tests.